# Button doesn't set to Enabled even after "if conditions" are met

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin

Below code is supposed to set "isEnabled" attribute of a button to *true*, but it doesn't. 
I initialize a mutable list which adds a String when certain Switches are on, and remove them when are off.

I created an if condition where if the size of the list is equal to 2 then *ok_button* is enabled.
I can't see why the *ok_button* is not updated even when the conditions are met.

```
package com.example.malakes
import android.nfc.Tag
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.CompoundButton
import android.widget.Switch
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object{ const val TAG = "MyActivity" } //define TAG

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val epilegmenoi: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

        val tony = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switchTony)
        val giorgis = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switchGiorgos)
        val duke = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switchDuke)
        val nikolas = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switchNikolas)
        val dionisis = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switchDionisis)
        val grigoris = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switchGrigoris)
        val ok_button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonOK)
        val clear_button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonCLEAR)

        tony.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                epilegmenoi.add("Tony")
            } else {
                epilegmenoi.remove("Tony")
            }


        }
        giorgis.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                epilegmenoi.add("Giorgis")
            } else {
                epilegmenoi.remove("Giorgis")
            }


        }

        if (epilegmenoi.size == 2) {ok_button.isEnabled=true}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‍`onCreate()` is a Lifecycle method in your activity. It is only called when your Activity is being called for the first time or when phone configs change, e.g. Screen Rotation, Locale change, and ...

Setting `if (epilegmenoi.size == 2) {ok_button.isEnabled=true}` inside onCreate doesn't do anything for you.

Consider moving this line of code to some Event-based function.

```
fun updateButtonState() {
    my_button.isEnabled = (myList.size == 2)
}
```

And inside your check box events:

```
tony.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        epilegmenoi.add("Tony")
    } else {
        epilegmenoi.remove("Tony")
    }
     updateButtonState()
}

giorgis.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        epilegmenoi.add("Giorgis")
    } else {
        epilegmenoi.remove("Giorgis")
    }
    updateButtonState()
}
```